# Overriding a Core Controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I have been trying to create a core Controller in Magento 1.5.0.1. I have followed the instructions to the letter from this site: http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/

The module is not showing up in the admin configuration, I would imagine that it is suppose to. Would anyone be able to advise please?

The config file is located at app/etc/modules and contains the exact code shown here:http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/  *

*sorry just figuring out how to put code markup on here, as it doesnt show up correctly.

Comment: Can you please write your code as well? So, that we can see what is wrong in the code (if it is so).

Comment: Hi Thanks. I have quite literally copied and pasted the code off the site above. With the only adjustment to the codePool in the xml file as per the comment on the blog.

Comment: To post code markup and show it correctly -> select your code and then click "{ }" icon present in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If the module doesn't show up, the first thing to is to clear caching, or perhaps disable it until you get the lesson working completely. Once you've done that, reload the page and then check the admin panel to see if it appears under the "Disable Modules" menu.

If it still doesn't work, please post your config.xml and also the location of your modules xml file.

Comment: @Joseph, you were faster on this one :)

Comment: Hi Joseph / OSdave. Thanks for your reply. I have disabled caching and also tried flushing the cache etc, but to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Also check that System -> Tools -> Compilation is disabled.

Comment: Hi Joseph / OSdave /Chapagain. Thanks for your reply. I have disabled caching and also tried flushing the cache etc, but to no avail unfortunately. Compilation is also off.  In app/etc < ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<inchoo_coreextended>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</inchoo_coreextended>
</modules>
</config> The module is located in the app/code/local/ Folder. I am not sure if there is a problem with PHP caching the data as we've had problems with APC and Memcache being on.

Comment: Please modify your post above with this information, rather than appending it in a comment. It's really difficult to quickly grok code without newlines.

Comment: sorry not to familiar with how to use stackoverflow yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with cache enabled? If so, disable it or refresh it everytime you make a change.
Have you you created your module's declaration xml file? (in app/etc/modules/).

Answer (score 0):

If your file

app/etc/modules/Inchoo_Coreextended.xml

exists and your cache is turned off and it is not listed under
System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable Modules Output

then you very likely have the wrong file permissions. Essentially the file is there but can't be read by the server. Check the file's user and group as well as its read/write permissions. If you are unsure you can compare it to
app/etc/local.xml

Comment: Hi, thanks, just checked that and the permissions are set to 755, but tried it in 777 too. Ps your speedster module is ace.